# Verilog: Warning (13410): Pin "pin_name2" is stuck at GND

Tags: fpga, verilog

I cannot understand why g and b are stuck. It is my understanding that `always@(posedge clock)` will execute any time clock input goes from 0 to 1. I have the clock pin connected to a pll that is driven by the FPGA's clock. My variable `count` should increment with each clock, and then `color` should increment every time that `count` wraps around. Can someone help explain what I am missing.

```
module state_machine ( clock, r, g, b );
input clock;
output reg r;
output reg g;
output reg b;

reg count;

reg color;

always@(posedge clock)
begin

if(count == 50000000) count = 0;
else count = count + 1;

if(count == 0) color = color + 1;
    
if(color > 1'o7) color = 1'o0;

r = color & 1'o1;
g = color & 1'o2;
b = color & 1'o4;

end
endmodule
```

Here is the error message from Quartus:

```
Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at state_machine.v(15): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (1)
Warning (10230): Verilog HDL assignment warning at state_machine.v(17): truncated value with size 32 to match size of target (1)
Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND
    Warning (13410): Pin "pin_name2" is stuck at GND
    Warning (13410): Pin "pin_name3" is stuck at GND
```

Comment: A hint: What is the value of `1'o4` (same goes for `1'o2`)

Comment: A second hint: What is the maximum value that can be stored in `reg count;`

Comment: A third hint: What is the maximum value that can be stored in `reg color;`

Comment: Finally, think about your if statements. What do you intend to happen if `color > 7` and `count == 0`.

Comment: Just to spare you the next gotchas, be sure to read [this](http://www.sutherland-hdl.com/papers/2007-SNUG-SanJose_gotcha_again_paper.pdf) in parallel to your verilog tutorial.

Comment: Or, to be less obtuse, how do you expect a 1-bit register to ever hold the value 50000000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I now have this and it works.

```
module state_machine ( clock, rgb );
input clock;
output reg[2:0] rgb;

reg[31:0] count;
reg[2:0] color;

always@(posedge clock)
begin

if(count == 50000000) count = 0;
else count = count + 1;

if(count == 0) rgb = rgb + 1'o1;

end
endmodule
```